# Adding sales tax rules for many countries

Tags: formula, math

I need to add sales tax rules for a whole host of countries (around 60) as my company is about to go global selling not just in the UK.

The company works with external suppliers taxed in their own region and we want SF to be aware of the local taxes and to include them in cost calculations.

In particular for the USA with different sales taxes in each state this seems like a bit of a nightmare to define all the rules for a lot of countries.   So does SF have anything built in to assist this process?

I've tried searching SF's own documentation but can't find confirmation so assume it doesn't, still if anyone can clarify this and ways to ease a lot of formula entry that would be most useful.

Comment: from my very own experience - there are nothing that can fit generic world tax system. when I met similar requirementes, it was decided to build own system, with lot of custom objects, that defines custom taxing countries, templates and rules per template, which are applied in corresponding order and via corresponding condition, which are defined as text, that describes some criteria of end taxable object( object with amount and types). But still, it is up to requirements